# Sitecore User Group Hyderabad Meetup - June 23, 2017

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

We are happy to announce the second installment of Sitecore Hyderabad User Group meetup new session in June 2017.

3 months passed by since we did last meetup in Hyderabad. Honouring the comments we received from last year meetup, we plan on doing quarterly meetups this year.

So, in this installment we are bringing new and useful topics.

1. **Sitecore EzImporter**: It is a shared source module for importing tabular data into Sitecore. It's unique because it maps tabular data to a tree structure by grouping the input data. It supports XLSX, XLS and CSV.
2. **Sitecore Skype Chatbot** that provides access to Sitecore CMS users for performing publishing, previewing and enquiring page visit metrics right from their Skype. It's powered by Azure Cognitive services to perform Natural Language Processing to respond to the user questions.
3. **Sitecore on Azure PaaS:** In this session Prawin will share his recent experience deploying Sitecore on Azure PaaS for one of his customers

**Agenda** (Below timezone in IST)

- 5:30 PM - 5:45 PM Networking
- 5:45 PM - 6:15 PM Using Sitecore Ez Importer  - Pratik Wasnik
- 6:15 PM - 6:45 PM Fun with Sitecore Skype Chatbots - Kishore Kumar Machineni
- 6:45 PM - 7:15 PM Sitecore on Azure PaaS
- 7:15 PM - 7:30 PM Wrap up

**When:**

- Date/Time (IST): Friday, June 23, 2017, 5:30 PM - 7:30 PM
- Date/Time (UTC): Friday, June 23, 2017, 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM

**Where**: Techaspect Solutions, Hyderabad, Telangana, India

**Contact Person**: [Phani Abburi](https://twitter.com/phani_abburi)

**RSVP Link**: https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Hyderabad/events/240755252/

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began yesterday